# The Steps to Base58-encode a Peercoin Public Key

Tags: php, c++

I hope someone can help me with this challenge. I would like to know the process that is used for converting a
hex-130 character Peercoin public key into a Peercoin address. If you can read C++, reading the source code here https://github.com/ppcoin/ppcoin/blob/master/src/base58.h#L1, will help.I need help adjusting this code to work for Peercoin (I got this code from a previous question on this site).
Let's use this for example,
130 Character Public Key: 04D166177BBC050D53ABD5197A1A0D1DAC31B14795E0A1C2267918FBEAF28DDCBB200D313541E8E5374E573FA570D8EA94FC44905243FAC2726D625C11A36C9A3E

The Base58-encoded Peercoin Address of the above is: PS8yhj8NjXpJG4AFx77AYjpS2DZ8ucCGJe

Note: This is a valid public key, I got this key from http://tizop.com/peercoin.htm and I tested it with ppcoind.

```
    <?php 

function hexStringToByteString($hexString){
    $len=strlen($hexString);

    $byteString="";
    for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i=$i+2){
        $charnum=hexdec(substr($hexString,$i,2));
        $byteString.=chr($charnum);
    }

return $byteString;
}

// BCmath version for huge numbers
function bc_arb_encode($num, $basestr) {
    if( ! function_exists('bcadd') ) {
        Throw new Exception('You need the BCmath extension.');
    }

    $base = strlen($basestr);
    $rep = '';

    while( true ){
        if( strlen($num) < 2 ) {
            if( intval($num) <= 0 ) {
                break;
            }
        }
        $rem = bcmod($num, $base);
        $rep = $basestr[intval($rem)] . $rep;
        $num = bcdiv(bcsub($num, $rem), $base);
    }
    return $rep;
}

function bc_arb_decode($num, $basestr) {
    if( ! function_exists('bcadd') ) {
        Throw new Exception('You need the BCmath extension.');
    }

    $base = strlen($basestr);
    $dec = '0';

    $num_arr = str_split((string)$num);
    $cnt = strlen($num);
    for($i=0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
        $pos = strpos($basestr, $num_arr[$i]);
        if( $pos === false ) {
            Throw new Exception(sprintf('Unknown character %s at offset %d', $num_arr[$i], $i));
        }
        $dec = bcadd(bcmul($dec, $base), $pos);
    }
    return $dec;
}


// base 58 alias
function bc_base58_encode($num) {   
    return bc_arb_encode($num, '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz');
}
function bc_base58_decode($num) {
    return bc_arb_decode($num, '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz');
}

//hexdec with BCmath
function bc_hexdec($num) {
    return bc_arb_decode(strtolower($num), '0123456789abcdef');
}
function bc_dechex($num) {

    return bc_arb_encode($num, '0123456789abcdef');
}

// step 1

$publickey='04D166177BBC050D53ABD5197A1A0D1DAC31B14795E0A1C2267918FBEAF28DDCBB200D313541E8E5374E573FA570D8EA94FC44905243FAC2726D625C11A36C9A3E';

$step1=hexStringToByteString($publickey);

//echo "step1 ".$step1."<br>";

// step 2

$step2=hash("sha256",$step1);
echo "step2 ".$step2."<br>";

// step 3

$step3=hash('ripemd160',hexStringToByteString($step2));
echo "step3 ".$step3."<br>";

// step 4

$step4='55'.$step3;
echo "step4 ".$step4."<br>";

// step 5

$step5=hash("sha256",hexStringToByteString($step4));
echo "step5 ".$step5."<br>";

// step 6

// $step6=hash("sha256",hexStringToByteString($step5));
// echo "step6 ".$step6."<br>";

// step 7

$checksum=substr($step5,0,8);
echo "step7 ".$checksum."<br>";

// step 8

$step8=$step4.$checksum;
echo "step8 ".$step8."<br>";




// step 9
// base conversion is from hex to base58 via decimal. 
// Leading hex zero converts to 1 in base58 but it is dropped
// in the intermediate decimal stage.  Simply added back manually.

$step9='P'.bc_base58_encode(bc_hexdec($step8));
echo "step9 ".$step9."<br><br>";

?>
```

This is my Output, as you can see my final line 
doesn't match with: **PS8yhj8NjXpJG4AFx77AYjpS2DZ8ucCGJe**

```
step1 04D166177BBC050D53ABD5197A1A0D1DAC31B14795E0A1C2267918FBEAF28DDCBB200D313541E8E5374E573FA570D8EA94FC44905243FAC2726D625C11A36C9A3E
step2 6cf59dae61a5b2a4ca2990c644fa7d444928175f1c454f0cf2f4d98081dc6f63
step3 c07de396ef663b22ccab46fc87d067eaad408aa3
step4 55c07de396ef663b22ccab46fc87d067eaad408aa3
step5 12c5b0698d8dd8bd9a9d653c6d09beaf67cb0b967107f835537f0ebd4e97df0d
step7 12c5b069
step8 55c07de396ef663b22ccab46fc87d067eaad408aa312c5b069
step9 PbWH5Ez522wiao4Lrgh6j6Vz2uMHSDNMRbe
```

Comment: Do you happen to know approximately where the first error happens?  Any idea whether the hashing steps are correct?

Comment: @ChristopherOicles,no, that is my issue, but I think that the process is correct up to step 4. I'm not that familiar with C++ and so I'm not sure how exactly the developer designed the hashing process. Also, I'd like to note that this code works nicely for coding bitcoin public keys (change the '55' to '0'), and so since Peercoin is based off of Bitcoin, I would think that the process is similar.

Comment: Alright, I made some progress. First off, I found out that Peercoin doesn't use SHA256D,it just uses SHA256, meaning that it doesn't double hash the ripemd160. So, you can see that in the code I double SHA256 hashed between steps 5 and 6, which is an error.However, even when I comment out the second sha256 hash and carry on with the process, I still get the wrong encoded public key address...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright! I ended up solving this myself. The biggest issue was that I used 55 as a decimal, when I should've converted 55decimal to hexadecimal, which is '37'. I also take back my comment on PPC only using sha256 and not sha256d.Peercoin uses sha256d. The public keys are base58 encoded the same way bitcoins are, but instead of using version number 1, it is 55, and 55 in hexadecimal is 37 (which I mentioned above). So, here's the final code and output.

Cheers.

```
    <?php 

function hexStringToByteString($hexString){
    $len=strlen($hexString);

    $byteString="";
    for ($i=0;$i<$len;$i=$i+2){
        $charnum=hexdec(substr($hexString,$i,2));
        $byteString.=chr($charnum);
    }

return $byteString;
}

// BCmath version for huge numbers
function bc_arb_encode($num, $basestr) {
    if( ! function_exists('bcadd') ) {
        Throw new Exception('You need the BCmath extension.');
    }

    $base = strlen($basestr);
    $rep = '';

    while( true ){
        if( strlen($num) < 2 ) {
            if( intval($num) <= 0 ) {
                break;
            }
        }
        $rem = bcmod($num, $base);
        $rep = $basestr[intval($rem)] . $rep;
        $num = bcdiv(bcsub($num, $rem), $base);
    }
    return $rep;
}

function bc_arb_decode($num, $basestr) {
    if( ! function_exists('bcadd') ) {
        Throw new Exception('You need the BCmath extension.');
    }

    $base = strlen($basestr);
    $dec = '0';

    $num_arr = str_split((string)$num);
    $cnt = strlen($num);
    for($i=0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
        $pos = strpos($basestr, $num_arr[$i]);
        if( $pos === false ) {
            Throw new Exception(sprintf('Unknown character %s at offset %d', $num_arr[$i], $i));
        }
        $dec = bcadd(bcmul($dec, $base), $pos);
    }
    return $dec;
}


// base 58 alias
function bc_base58_encode($num) {   
    return bc_arb_encode($num, '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz');
}
function bc_base58_decode($num) {
    return bc_arb_decode($num, '123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz');
}

//hexdec with BCmath
function bc_hexdec($num) {
    return bc_arb_decode(strtolower($num), '0123456789abcdef');
}
function bc_dechex($num) {

    return bc_arb_encode($num, '0123456789abcdef');
}


$publickey='04D166177BBC050D53ABD5197A1A0D1DAC31B14795E0A1C2267918FBEAF28DDCBB200D313541E8E5374E573FA570D8EA94FC44905243FAC2726D625C11A36C9A3E';

//step1 is just converting the 130-hex-character publickey in bytes
$step1=hexStringToByteString($publickey);

echo "step1 ".$publickey."<br>";

// step 2 sha256 hashes the publickey from step 1

$step2=hash("sha256",$step1);
echo "step2 ".$step2."<br>";

// step 3 ripemd160 hashes step2

$step3=hash('ripemd160',hexStringToByteString($step2));
echo "step3 ".$step3."<br>";

// step 4 is the tricky part: add 37(hexadecimal of 55)the
// version number to step 3

$step4='37'.$step3;
echo "step4 ".$step4."<br>";

// step 5 sha256 hash step4 

$step5=hash("sha256",hexStringToByteString($step4));
echo "step5 ".$step5."<br>";

// step 6 sha256 hash step 5

$step6=hash("sha256",hexStringToByteString($step5));
echo "step6 ".$step6."<br>";

// step 7 takes the first 8 characters (4 bytes) of step 6 as a checksum

$checksum=substr($step6,0,8);
echo "step7 ".$checksum."<br>";

// step 8 adds the checksum to step 4

$step8=$step4.$checksum;
echo "step8 ".$step8."<br>";


//step 9 converts step 8 into decimal
$step9=bc_hexdec($step8);


//step 10 encodes step 9 into base58
$step10=bc_base58_encode($step9);
echo "step9 ".$step10."<br><br>";

?>
```

Remember that the base58 public key is **PS8yhj8NjXpJG4AFx77AYjpS2DZ8ucCGJe**.

```
step1 04D166177BBC050D53ABD5197A1A0D1DAC31B14795E0A1C2267918FBEAF28DDCBB200D313541E8E5374E573FA570D8EA94FC44905243FAC2726D625C11A36C9A3E
step2 6cf59dae61a5b2a4ca2990c644fa7d444928175f1c454f0cf2f4d98081dc6f63
step3 c07de396ef663b22ccab46fc87d067eaad408aa3
step4 37c07de396ef663b22ccab46fc87d067eaad408aa3
step5 a4237928cd0a9cbb001325a9b4726633ed67fd0ce15bf50c7d19260a297f488b
step6 443e1443a9fbdc855b88865e621fc5b35fe4515bc35229460ccb9f277dd35c21
step7 443e1443
step8 37c07de396ef663b22ccab46fc87d067eaad408aa3443e1443
step9 PS8yhj8NjXpJG4AFx77AYjpS2DZ8ucCGJe
```

As you can probably see, they MATCH!